# How to get the value with getElementById in a class and use it in a different class

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        Input
        <form class="form-inline" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">

                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="getString" placeholder="Enter some string">

            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="nowBtn">Now</button>
        </form>

        <br/>
        <br/>

        All Headings<textarea class="form-control" rows="6"></textarea>
    </div>   
</body>
```

I am using bootstrap and I will give some string in the form, when the Now button is pressed.
I should get the `<h1>` tag of that string in the textarea (i.e `<h1>some string</h1>` in the textarea with applied `<h1>` tag ).

Is it achievable? I want to use jQuery.

Comment: Please, someone who is good at English, edit this question. I am not doing it because english is not my first language

Comment: @Huangism sorry, what did u didn't understand?

Comment: The OP is still lonely.

Comment: h1 tag in html
used for headings

Comment: You can't use HTML in the inputs value, if that's what you're trying to do, at least it won't render as only strings are allowed ?

Comment: I'm not using html, I want to get the font size in the text area as of h1 heading tag

Comment: Perhaps he wants to take the "text" from the input and add html markup like any html wysiwyg editor has to do to make valid html.

Comment: Basically when the form is submitted take some data from the form and put it in a Heading Element, then put that Heading element in a textarea. No this is not possible

Comment: @Connor: I don't want h1 in the text area
I want the text applied with h1 tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments I've understood you'd like to set the `font-size` in the `textarea` to same size as `h1` tag would have.

Since there's no `h1` tag in your HTML, you need to create a one in the click event handler function of the `#nowBtn`:

```
var header = document.createElement('h1'),
    size = window.getComputedStyle(header, null).fontSize; // Depending used browser and CSS, this returns for example 32px
```

Then you can set the `font-size` of `textarea` like this:

```
$('textarea').css('font-size', size);
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DxVn2/2/).

**EDIT**

As bfavaretto has mentioned, a cross-browser way would be to use jQuery to get the size of the `h1`:

```
size = $(header).css('font-size');
```

Comment: Why didn't you use jquery to get the size too?

Comment: @bfavaretto My jQuery skills are so poor... Can those two lines even be shorter/faster?

Comment: What I mean is you can use `size = $(header).css('font-size')` to get the computed style of the newly created h1 (and it's cross-browser).

Comment: @bfavaretto Oh, I didn't realize, that jQuery would find non-appended elements too. With your permission I'll change the answer. And thanks for the info : ).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this fiddle - it might be what you want.
http://jsfiddle.net/Nj7pj/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btn-primary').on('click', function () {
        inputVal = $('#getString').val();
        newTextAreaVal = "<h1>" + inputVal + "</h1>";
        $('textarea').val(newTextAreaVal);
    });
});
```

Comment: h1 is not a value here,
h1 is heading tag in html,
I want that text as that big

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do

```
var h1 = $("h1.classYouWant"); 
$(".form-control").val( "<h1>" + h1.text() + "</h1>" );
```

if is dynamic the header (h1 or h2 or h3 )

you can do

```
var header = $(".classYouWant").get(0);
$(".form-control").val( header.outerHTML );
```