# Get a css value from Bootstrap css with JavaScript/ jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to get the font sizes of headings `h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6` which are respectively `36px, 30px, 24px, 18px, 14px, 12px` respectively [in bootstrap.css] and alert them in the console. The jQuery method I've seen is `$('element').css('property')`, but this is not working for external css [i.e bootstrap.css].
Should I have to include any more lines of code.

Comment: why do you want to do it?

Comment: I am inputting a string via form and want to have all type of headings of that string  from h1 to h6 in a textbox.

Comment: for that why do you want to know the css property value

Comment: then I can give the value to font-size  $textarea.css('font-size', value);

Comment: oh, I just recognized that , if I do that the font-size will be fixed for that textbox, is there any way to do that.

Comment: Perhaps this will help: [Can jQuery get all CSS styles associated with an element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element) (there are a few of these solutions here)

Comment: The answer I gave you for your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18337531/1169519) of this is perfectly valid, it definitely works also with external stylesheets. You've missed something else, for example: are the font-sizes of the `H*` tags defined by classes or by tag selectors?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(['h1','h2','h3','h4','h5','h6'], function(idx, val){
    console.log($(val).css('font-size') )
});
```

Comment: The OP mentioned that this method did not work in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

```
var stylesheet = document.styleSheets[(document.styleSheets.length - 1)];

for( var i in document.styleSheets ){
     var temp = = document.styleSheets[i];
     if( temp.href && temp.href.indexOf("bootstrap.css") ) {
        stylesheet = temp;
        break;
     }
}
var ruleList = stylesheet.cssRules, allRules = [];
for (var rule = 0; rule < ruleList.length; rule ++){
   allRules.push( [rule, ruleList[rule].selectorText] );
}
console.log(addRules);
```